# Pandas: How to filter repeated values of an axis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Let's assume that we've got a dataframe composed of the following variables, among others:

```
Institution (name of the university)
Country (name of the country of the institution)
Year (integer, year in which that university was scored)
World_rank (integer, position in the world rank)
Alumni_employment (integer, number of alumni placements)
```

We want to filter all American-based universities, which were ranked <= 500 in 2015 and share the same value for Alumni_employment.

While the first 3 requirements are easy to meet, i got stuck at the last one.

Here it goes my attempt at this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("data/cwurData.csv")

americanuniv = data[(data.country == 'USA') & (data.year == 2015) & (data.world_rank <= 500)]
for x in data.alumni_employment:
    for y in data.alumni_employment:
        if x == y:   
            print(americanuniv['institution'])
```

Naturally, it didn't work. To be hinest, I don't know how to move forward to accomplish the last challenge.. Do you guys have any thought about this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The last requirement is a bit ambiguous. You might have uni A and uni B that have the same alumni_employment (say 10), while uni C and uni D might have the same alumni employment with each other (say 20), but not with A and B. Would you want to list A, B, C, and D in that case?

Comment: Hi @Burrito, I'm afraid I need to 'group' A, B, C & D only if they all have the same alumni_employment. I thought that iterating would be a good option but that's precisely where I got stuck. Thanks for your swift reply!

Comment: You can use groupby('alumni_employment') to get the groups you want, and then it depends what you want to do after that. Just print the rows in their groups?

Comment: Mmm.. I tried to do it the other way round. First grouping by alumni and then applying the filters but it didn't work. What I would need to print are the rows correctly filtered and grouped so that only those who meet all the conditions are displayed. The point is how can I do to state 'only those who have the same alumni value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let's use the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'institution': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 
  'alumni_employment': [10, 20, 10, 30, 20, 5, 20]})
```

To get institutions with the same 'alumni_employment', use groupby. Then, filter to eliminate the ones in groups of size 1.

```
g = df.groupby('alumni_employment')
final = g.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

The result is:

```
    institution alumni_employment
0   A           10
1   B           20
2   C           10
4   E           20
6   G           20
```

If you want the ones with the same 'alumni_employment' to be printed together, you can do:

```
final = final.sort_values('alumni_employment')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Burrito! Now you gave me food for thought :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    americanuniv = data.loc[(data["country"] == 'USA') & (data["year"] == 2015) & (data["world_rank"] <= 500)]
    americanuniv.groupby(by = "Alumni_employment")["institution"]
```

Comment: It had the same effect as my code without the 'for' loop but thanks for trying!